# I'm getting whole html of my page when try to get data from server by $.ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I working on an asp.net website and I want to get some simple data from server like time by clicking a `div` in the page using jquery `$.ajax` method but when I trying to get this data whole html of my page is shown in the `div`

my c# code behind is something like this :

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string getCurrentDate()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

and my js is :

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#getDateByClick').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Default.aspx/getCurrentDate',
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#getDateByClick').text(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: What does `Default.aspx/getCurrentDate` return?

Comment: I think your server side script return whole website.. please check your layout on the server side script..

Comment: it returns string as in the c# code

Comment: so the problem solved.It seems that the `[WebMethod]` return type is `JSON` and `contentType`,`dataType` in the `$.ajax` must be set to json
so I set `contentType`,`dataType` in my javascript code and it's working now 

`contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json"`

thank you